# How to tell what version of Intel compiler was used to compile binary

Tags: c, fortran, symbols, intel

So it is relatively straightforward to tell from the symbols embedded in an executable if an Intel compiler was used to compile it, e.g. from the presence of symbols like __intel_proc_init in the executable.

Is there a way to tell what version of the Intel compiler was used to compile the binary using similar diagnostics?

Comment: Have you played around with `objdump` to see if there's any trace of a version tag somewhere?

Comment: The only thing I've found is a symbol called intel_id.71.0.0.0 but it's unclear what that means.

Answer (score 2):

So I think I figured out a partial answer to my own question. Using the strings utility, I was able to extract the following strings from the Fortran executable:

> @(#)Intel Fortran RTL Message Catalog V10.1-101 01-Aug-2007

from another Fortran executable, I found the following strings:

> /opt/intel/Compiler/11.1/073/bin/intel64/ifort
>
> @(#)Intel Fortran RTL Message Catalog V11.1-107 16-Mar-2010

however, I was not able to extract any such string from C compiled executables.

Answer (score 1):

PEID is able to do this for MSVC binaries, so you may want to check it out and see if it works for intel, if so then you'd need to find out from the makers what they scan for in the PE/obj dump (iirc some of the info is in plain text in the PE)

Comment: I don't have a Windows platform to use so I can't try this method. Thanks for telling me about PEID though, it sounds useful.

Answer (score 0):

The following Fortran source code will output the Intel compiler version at run-time.   Obviously similar code in other languages....   Will that meet your need?  If not, it might give a clue to a symbol in the executable.

```
#ifdef __INTEL_COMPILER
      write  (*, 1050)  __INTEL_COMPILER
      1050 format ( "Fortran code compiled with Intel ifort, version ", I0 / )
#endif
```

Comment: Thanks, but my original question was regarding the case where I only have the final compiled executable and not the source.